# Print CGAL arrangement with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cgal

I am using a CGAL Arrangement.

Here is my `Arrangement_2` type:

```
typedef CGAL::CORE_algebraic_number_traits              Nt_traits;
typedef Nt_traits::Rational                             Rational;
typedef Nt_traits::Algebraic                            Algebraic;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Rational>                       Rat_kernel;
typedef Rat_kernel::Point_2                             Rat_point_2;
typedef Rat_kernel::Segment_2                           Rat_segment_2;
typedef Rat_kernel::Circle_2                            Rat_circle_2;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<Algebraic>                      Alg_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Arr_conic_traits_2<Rat_kernel, Alg_kernel, Nt_traits> Traits_2;
typedef Traits_2::Point_2                               Point_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                               Conic_arc_2;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits_2>                   Arrangement_2;
```

I would like to know how can I print this `Arrangement_2` in a Qt window. I would really appreciate an example.

Comment: What do you want to print? The type? The contents - if so, exactly what contents?

Comment: I want to print (in a window) all the arragement's conics edge (segment, circle, circle arc). Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code of the Qt demo in `demo/Arrangement_on_surface_2`, in the CGAL tarball. There should be everything you need.